# ¿Por qué mi componente React hijo se recarga a veces (retornándome al padre) y otras veces no, cuando selecciono imágenes y las envío al backend?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, multer

Cuando selecciono imágenes de un simple input y pulso mi botón, estas deben enviarse a mi backend y guardarse en base de datos, esto lo hace perfecto: el misterioso problema es que a veces al pulsar el botón para enviar las imágenes mi componente hijo hace un reload y se devuelve a mi componente padre (esto no debería pasar), otras veces trabaja correctamente, es decir pulso mi botón de envío de imágenes, se envían las imágenes y mi componente hijo permanece bien sin hacer reload y sin devolverse a mi componente padre.

Les dejo el código del componente padre y componente hijo, así como también el archivo server y mi archivo de rutas. Por cierto, ya he probado hacer el preventDefault del "form" pero no me ha funcionado, sigue el reload del componente hijo con retorno al componete padre, incluso hice un preventDefault del botón y nada funcionó:

```
    $("#formElem").submit(function(event){     event.preventDefault(); });
    $('#formElem').submit(false);
    $('#boton').on('click', function (event) {             event.preventDefault(); });
```

Componente padre:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import CargarArchivos from './CargarArchivos'

function App() {
 const [comparacion, setComparacion] = useState(false) 
 const [idusuario, setIdusuario] = useState('') 
 const [nombreEmpresa, setNombreEmpresa] = useState('') 

 const llamarCargarArchivos =()=>{
       setComparacion(true)

       setIdusuario(62)
       setNombreEmpresa('supeco')

 }

 let lineas = (
          <button onClick={llamarCargarArchivos}></button>
 )

 
 return (
   comparacion ? <CargarArchivos pepe={pepe} idusuario={idusuario} nombreEmpresa={nombreEmpresa}></CargarArchivos>: lineas
 );
}

export default App;
```

Componente hijo:

```
import React, {useRef} from 'react';


function CargarArchivos(props){

    const elementRef = useRef();

    const onSubmit = (e) =>{ 
        e.preventDefault();
        e.stopPropagation();


        /*$("#formElem").submit(function(event){   event.preventDefault(); });
        $('#formElem').submit(false);
        $('#boton').on('click', function (event) {      event.preventDefault(); });*/


       const formdata = new FormData(document.getElementById('formElem'));

       formdata.append('idusuario',props.idusuario); 
       formdata.append('nombreEmpresa',props.nombreEmpresa);


       fetch('http://localhost:3001/images/post', {
        method: 'POST',
        body: formdata

       })
       .then((response) => response.json())
       .then(response => {
           console.log('Success:', response);
       })
       .catch((error) => {
           console.error('Error:', error);
       });


    }  

  return (
      <div > 
        <form id="formElem">
            <input type="file" name="picture" id="picture"  multiple />
            <input type="text" name="texto" id="texto" ref={elementRef} />
            <input type="button" id="boton" onClick={onSubmit}/>
        </form>
    </div>
  )
}

export default CargarArchivos;
```

Mi backend - server:

```
const express = require("express");
const mysql = require('mysql')
const myconn = require('express-myconnection')
const app = express();
const cors = require("cors")

app.use(express.json());
app.use(cors());

app.use(myconn(mysql, {
   host: 'localhost',
   port: 3306,
   user: 'root',
   password: '',
   database: 'tienda'
 }))

 
app.use(require('./routes.js'));



app.set('port',process.env.PORT || 3001);

app.listen(app.get('port'),()=>{
   console.log("Servidor corriendo por el puerto", app.get('port'));
})
```

Extracto de mi archivo Routes:

```
router.post('/images/post',fileUpload, (req, res) => {

   //HAGO UNA CONEXION CON MI BASE DE DATOS
   req.getConnection((err, conn) => {


     var mensaje
     for (var i = 0; i < req.files.length; i++) {
   
           const name = req.files[i].originalname
   
           //LEO TODAS LAS IMAGENES DEL CLIENTE DE SU CARPETA 
           let archivos = fs.readdirSync('./public/clientes/'+`${nombreEmpresa}/`) 

           const ruta = `${nombreEmpresa}/` + req.files[i].originalname.replace(' ', '_').toLocaleLowerCase()
   
           var post  = {idusuario: idusuario , nombreOriginal: name, rutaFisicaCarpetaCliente: ruta};
   
           
           conn.query('INSERT INTO imagenes set ?', post, (err,rows) => {           
             if (err){mensaje=err}
             else{
               if(rows){mensaje='Se guardaron las imagenes'}
             }

           })        

     }  

     res.send({msg:mensaje})
         
 })

}
```

Comment: Yo implementaría una validación para `formdata`, antes de entrar al `fetch`. Y también envolvería el `fetch` en un `try/catch`. Saludos

Comment: Hola g.4 gracias por responder, estimado amigo podrias indicarme que validacion harias tu del formdata, podrias sugerirme un codigo ?

Comment: Ya revise el caso y no he logrado reproducir el problema que mencionas, con el código que nos muestras; he enviando el form alrededor de 50 veces consecutivas y no se recarga el componente Padre. Ahora bien, la única forma de que el componente Parte se recarge, es si cambia alguno de los estados de los que es dueño; que en este caso son `comparacion`, `ideusuario` y `nombreEmpresa`; ¿Estas seguro de que no hay otro estado involucrado entre el Padre y el Hijo?

Comment: Si puedes también listar los pasos que sigues para generar el problema que describes de forma mas precisa; Y agregalos a la pregunta; por ejemplo, cuantas imágenes subes, cada cuantos submit pasa esto. No puede ser tan "random" como un "a veces", saludos

Answer (score 1):

> En principio agradezco a [g.4](/users/101408) por su gentileza en responder y tomarse el tiempo para indagar sobre este problema.

Pude resolver el problema, honestamente no fui yo, me llegó una idea que se que vino de lo alto: comencé a guardar las imágenes de una en una **hasta que intenté guardar una imagen que había guardado antes (o sea imagen repetida) y ¡boom! el reload**.

Al seleccionar imágenes mediante un input de `type=file` yo las guardaba mediante multer en mi backend en una carpeta temporal X con el nombre original de cada imagen, adicionalmente uso la función `copySync` que me copia todas y cada una de mis imágenes de la carpeta temporal X a una carpeta Y.

El reload de la página se originaba cuando al seleccionar una imagen (repetida) que ya había seleccionado antes e intentar copiar esta con `copySync` de la carpeta X a la carpeta Y. En conclusión, el culpable del reload es la función `copySync` que falla cuando intentas copiar una imagen previamente guardada nuevamente de la carpeta X a la carpeta Y...

No sé por que la función `copySync` ocasiona este reload, pero lo que sí aconsejo encarecidamente es que cuando se trabaje con almacenamiento de imágenes se le cambie el nombre original de cada imagen a un nombre aleatorio, para esto se puede usar `uuidv4()` que genera letras y números aleatorios al nombre de archivo: esto evitará que si el cliente selecciona nuevamente una imagen que ya habia sido guardada antes la función `copySync`, no ocasione el reload de la página. Jamás hubiese imaginado que el `copySync` fuera el culpable del reload.

Comment: No olvides [aceptar](/help/accepted-answer) tu respuesta, y evita dirigirte a una persona en particular al responder. Las respuestas son _para todos_.